# Webservice HttpStatusCode 500 but not in browser

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf-binding

When I start a new HttpBasicBinding to a web service which is not initiated yet, because the app pool is not started will result in an Internal Server Error 500. But when I start the Web Service from the browser the service is being started.

How can I start the web service before sending a new request?

Below my code:

```
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
                binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
                binding.Name = "AXDocumentBinding";

                EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl);

AA_DynamicsAXDocuHandlingClient cls = new AA_DynamicsAXDocuHandlingClient(binding, address);
                cls.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

string retVal = cls.loadDocumentStr(AreaId, documentFileName, documentIdentification1, documentIdentification2, documentIdentification3, documentIdentification4, documentIdentification5, documentTable);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "Start a new HttpBasicBInding" ?

Comment: I mean, how do I create a session that the web service is being started, instead of returning a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: I just edited my post